# I can't see my Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a problem , I cant see my data  Realtime Database  its blocked by the layout that ask to activate the Realtime Database but mine is already active and well set. Someone has any idea how to fix it ? I cant work because of that

[image: This is what is shown]

Comment: Can you add `hl=en` to the URL in your browser and take/post another screenshot?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't been using Firestore up until now or are viewing a different project ID?

Comment: Have you tried re-activating it?

Comment: Hi Sir @Frank van Puffelen where do I am supposed to post the hl=en ? I posted it at the end of my url and nothing happenend

Comment: Hi @DIGIByte no im not using firestore just the real time database and the storage , but I ve reached my quota last month im still using the spark service for now

Comment: @Darky Adding `?hl=en` sets the language to English, which will make the error message readable to folks that don't speak French.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi , I ve just added the same image with english text  , thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It seems your database got into this state by accident, which should not be happening. I asked our engineers to look into it, and they manually reenabled the database. It might take a few moments for it to become active again.

They are looking into finding a root cause - and then fixing it. If this happens again in the meantime, please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they can from that more directly look at your project.

Comment: Thanks you for the help the I have acces to my database again and thanks to a part of the reason I will succes my dreams

Comment: Good to hear it started working again   And thanks for the clear report, which helped getting this fixed quickly. The engineers are still working on a full fix, so if it happens again please report here or to support.

Answer (score 0):

Try activating the database, ensure you are on the correct project and that it is the correct realtime database vs firestore.
If that fails, you will need to report a bug to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support)

Comment: When I click on the button nothing happens and yes you right I will send a mail to   Firebase Support